# Ember Simple Auth transition after login

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-simple-auth

I have login code on my application route, as per examples in the docs, but the call to authenticate does not seem to return a promise. The response I get in 'then' is undefined. Therefore the transition does not work. I have to manually refresh the page, and then the top redirect is called.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

// Make 'session' available throughout the application
import ApplicationRouteMixin from 'simple-auth/mixins/application-route-mixin';

export default Ember.Route.extend(ApplicationRouteMixin, {
  redirect: function () {
    this.transitionTo('orders');
  },
  actions: {
      authenticate: function () {
        var data = {
          identification: this.controller.get('identification'),
          password: this.controller.get('password')
        };

        this.get('session').authenticate('simple-auth-authenticator:oauth2-password-grant', data).then(
          function(response) {
            console.log(response); // undefined
            this.transitionTo('orders'); // can't call on undefined
          }
        );
      },
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

My issue was 'this' inside the function call was the wrong object. Solved by using var _this = this;

I'll post the full working code.;

```
import Ember from 'ember';

// Make 'session' available throughout the application
import ApplicationRouteMixin from 'simple-auth/mixins/application-route-mixin';

export default Ember.Route.extend(ApplicationRouteMixin, {
  redirect: function () {
    this.transitionTo('orders');
  },
  actions: {
      authenticate: function () {
        var data = {
          identification: this.controller.get('identification'),
          password: this.controller.get('password')
        };
        var _this = this;
        this.get('session').authenticate('simple-auth-authenticator:oauth2-password-grant', data).then(
          function(response) {
            console.log(_this.get('session')); // this correctly gets the session
            _this.transitionTo('orders');
          }
        );
      },
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The promise returned by the session's `authenticate` method doesn't resolve with a value. You can access data that the authenticator resolves with via the session's `secure` property, e.g. `this.get('session.secure.token)'`.

Comment: Marco I get it now, 'this' inside the function has the wrong context. I have posted the full working code, in case it helps someone. Thanks for your help, was scratching my head for a long time on this one last night!

Comment: You should use an arrow function instead so you don't have to assign the extra `_this`. The point is that you're using a `response` argument in the callback which will always be undefined.